# ¿Cómo solucionar error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"..?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Lo que pasa es que Tengo un `JFrame1` en el que quiero validar si en el `JTable` del `JFrame2` esta vacío que me ejecute alguna sentencia, y no me funciona, el JTable sí lo tengo como publico y estático y aún así me marca el error.

Yo pienso pasa eso a la hora de querer contar filas (.**getRowCount**) de un `JTable` que esta en el `JFrame2`, no sé que se podría hacer.

Aquí les dejó mi código:

Este es del **JFrame1**:

```
package Formularios;

import static Formularios.Carrito.JT_Carrito;
import static Formularios.Login.JTF_usuario;
import Logica.Cls_Rentas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
public class Ventana_Rentas extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
private final Cls_Rentas CP;
int num = 0;//Para agregar(0)/modificar(1).
int modo = 0;//Para el modo usuario o admin.

public Ventana_Rentas() 
{
    initComponents();
    String Modo = JTF_usuario.getText();
    if(Modo.equals("Admin"))
    {
        setTitle("MOBILIARIO - MODO ADMINISTRADOR");
    }
    else
    {
        setTitle("MOBILIARIO - MODO USUARIO");
        modo=1;
    }
    setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../Imagenes/DRey_Logo.jpg")).getImage());
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(51,0,0));
    cerrar();
    setVisible(true);
    CP = new Cls_Rentas();
    listar();
}


public void cerrar()
{
    try
    {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                confirmarSalida();
            }
        });
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: " + e);
    }
}
public void confirmarSalida()
{
    int Valor = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "¿Seguro que deseas salir?, todo lo del carrito se te eliminará si no has guardado.", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(Valor == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {   int dat=0;
        int r=JT_Carrito.getRowHeight();

        /*for (int a = 0; a < JT_Carrito.getRowCount(); a++)
        {
            dat++;
        }*/

        if(r==0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vacio");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Vacio");
            //AUMENTA UN CONTADOR DE MANERA QUE SI EL CONTADOR ES DIFERENTE DE CERO QUIERE DECIR QUE HAY MAS DE UN CAMPO VACIO........
        } 

        /*for (int i = 0; i < JT_Carrito.getRowCount(); i++)
        {//Recorre la tabla para sacar los valores y poder sumar y eliminar cuando se salga del programa.
            String id_mob_up = JT_Carrito.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
            String valor = JT_Carrito.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
            int tot_rent = Integer.parseInt(valor);
            CP.updateDatosSumMobCarrito(id_mob_up,tot_rent);
        }

        CP.deleteDatosCarrito();*/
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hasta Pronto.", "Gracias", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void listar()
{
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.setModel(CP.getDatos_Mobiliario());
}

public void limpiar()
{
    JTF_Id_Renta.setText("");
    JTF_Id_Mobiliario.setText("");
    JTF_Total_Rentados.setText("");
}

public void añadir_carrito()
{
    int id_mob = Integer.parseInt(JTF_Id_Mobiliario.getText());
    String id_mob_up = JTF_Id_Mobiliario.getText(); //Esta variable es para cuando se vaya a actualizar a la hora de ingresar mermas.
    String art_m = JCB_Articulo_Rentas.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int tot_rent = Integer.parseInt(JTF_Total_Rentados.getText());
    CP.InsertDatosCarrito(id_mob, art_m, tot_rent);
    CP.updateDatosRestMobCarrito(id_mob_up,tot_rent);
    listar();//Para que se actualice los datos en la tabla.
    limpiar();//limpia pantalla.
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    JL_Logo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    JB_Regresar_Rentas = new javax.swing.JButton();
    JL_Id_Renta = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    JL_Id_Mobiliario = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    JL_Articulo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    JL_Rentados = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas = new JTable(){

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {

            return false; //Las celdas no son editables.

        }
    };

    JTableHeader th;
    th = JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.getTableHeader();
    th.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    th.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    th.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255)); ;
    JCB_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    JTF_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    JB_Añadir_Carrito = new javax.swing.JButton();
    JB_Ver_Rentas = new javax.swing.JButton();
    JTF_Id_Renta = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    JTF_Id_Mobiliario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    JTF_Total_Rentados = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    JCB_Articulo_Rentas = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    JB_Ver_Carrito = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

    JL_Logo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/DRey_Logo_Frame.jpg"))); // NOI18N

    JB_Regresar_Rentas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JB_Regresar_Rentas.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    JB_Regresar_Rentas.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JB_Regresar_Rentas.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/return.png"))); // NOI18N
    JB_Regresar_Rentas.setText("REGRESAR");
    JB_Regresar_Rentas.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            JB_Regresar_RentasActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    JL_Id_Renta.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JL_Id_Renta.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JL_Id_Renta.setText("ID RENTA:");

    JL_Id_Mobiliario.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JL_Id_Mobiliario.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JL_Id_Mobiliario.setText("ID MOBILIARIO:");

    JL_Articulo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JL_Articulo.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JL_Articulo.setText("ARTICULO:");

    JL_Rentados.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JL_Rentados.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JL_Rentados.setText("TOTAL RENTADOS:");

    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(java.awt.Color.gray, java.awt.Color.darkGray));
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {}
        },
        new String [] {

        }
    ));
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    JT_Mobiliario_Rentas.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            JT_Mobiliario_RentasMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(JT_Mobiliario_Rentas);

    JCB_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JCB_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JCB_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JCB_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "ID", "ARTICULO" }));
    JCB_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));

    JTF_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JTF_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JTF_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JTF_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));
    JTF_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            JTF_Buscar_Articulos_RentasKeyReleased(evt);
        }
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            JTF_Buscar_Articulos_RentasKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    JB_Añadir_Carrito.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JB_Añadir_Carrito.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JB_Añadir_Carrito.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JB_Añadir_Carrito.setText("AÑADIR AL CARRITO");
    JB_Añadir_Carrito.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));
    JB_Añadir_Carrito.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            JB_Añadir_CarritoMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    JB_Ver_Rentas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JB_Ver_Rentas.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JB_Ver_Rentas.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JB_Ver_Rentas.setText("VER RENTAS");
    JB_Ver_Rentas.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));
    JB_Ver_Rentas.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            JB_Ver_RentasMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    JTF_Id_Renta.setEditable(false);
    JTF_Id_Renta.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JTF_Id_Renta.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JTF_Id_Renta.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JTF_Id_Renta.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));
    JTF_Id_Renta.setCaretColor(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0));

    JTF_Id_Mobiliario.setEditable(false);
    JTF_Id_Mobiliario.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JTF_Id_Mobiliario.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JTF_Id_Mobiliario.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JTF_Id_Mobiliario.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));
    JTF_Id_Mobiliario.setCaretColor(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0));

    JTF_Total_Rentados.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JTF_Total_Rentados.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JTF_Total_Rentados.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JTF_Total_Rentados.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));
    JTF_Total_Rentados.setCaretColor(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0));

    JCB_Articulo_Rentas.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JCB_Articulo_Rentas.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JCB_Articulo_Rentas.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JCB_Articulo_Rentas.setMaximumRowCount(9);
    JCB_Articulo_Rentas.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "PLATO TRINCHE CUADRADO", "PLATO TRINCHE REDONDO", "PLATO SOPERO CUADRADO", "PLATO SOPERO REDONDO", "PLATO BASE", "PLATO PASTELERO CUADRADO", "PLATO PASTELERO REDONDO", "PLATO CAFETERO CUADRADO", "PLATO CAFETERO REDONDO", "BOWLS", "VASO HAIL VALL", "VASO JUGUERO", "TAZA CUADRADA", "TAZA REDONDA", "COPA FLAUTA", "COPA GLOBO", "COPA MARTINERA", "COPA MARGARITA", "COPA COÑACQUERA" }));
    JCB_Articulo_Rentas.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));

    JB_Ver_Carrito.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 153, 0));
    JB_Ver_Carrito.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    JB_Ver_Carrito.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 0));
    JB_Ver_Carrito.setText("VER CARRITO");
    JB_Ver_Carrito.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(153, 51, 0), 3, true));
    JB_Ver_Carrito.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            JB_Ver_CarritoMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(JCB_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(JB_Regresar_Rentas)
                    .addComponent(JL_Id_Renta)
                    .addComponent(JL_Id_Mobiliario)
                    .addComponent(JL_Articulo)
                    .addComponent(JL_Rentados)))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(JL_Logo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 285, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(JTF_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 648, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(188, 188, 188)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(JTF_Id_Renta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(JTF_Id_Mobiliario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(JTF_Total_Rentados, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(JCB_Articulo_Rentas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 332, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(251, 251, 251)
                    .addComponent(JB_Añadir_Carrito, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 223, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(JB_Ver_Rentas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 223, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(JB_Ver_Carrito, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 223, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(156, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(JL_Logo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 144, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(JB_Regresar_Rentas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(JL_Id_Renta)
                        .addComponent(JTF_Id_Renta, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(JL_Id_Mobiliario)
                        .addComponent(JTF_Id_Mobiliario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(JL_Articulo)
                        .addComponent(JCB_Articulo_Rentas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(JL_Rentados)
                        .addComponent(JTF_Total_Rentados, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 24, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(JB_Ver_Rentas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(JB_Añadir_Carrito, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(JB_Ver_Carrito, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(JTF_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(JCB_Buscar_Articulos_Rentas, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 313, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void JB_Regresar_RentasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    Ventana_Principal ventana = new Ventana_Principal();
    ventana.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../Imagenes/DRey_Logo.jpg")).getImage());

    if(JT_Carrito.getRowCount()!=0 && JT_Carrito.getSelectedRow()!=-1)//Comprueba que la tabla este vacía.
    {
        String Mod = JTF_usuario.getText();
        if(Mod.equals("Admin"))
        {
            ventana.setTitle("VENTANA PRINCIPAL - MODO ADMINISTRADOR");
        }
        else
        {
            ventana.setTitle("VENTANA PRINCIPAL - MODO USUARIO");
        }
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        /*for (int i = 0; i < JT_Carrito.getRowCount(); i++)
        {//Recorre la tabla para sacar los valores y poder sumar y eliminar cuando se salga del programa.
            String id_mob_up = JT_Carrito.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
            String valor = JT_Carrito.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
            int tot_rent = Integer.parseInt(valor);
            CP.updateDatosSumMobCarrito(id_mob_up,tot_rent);
        }
        CP.deleteDatosCarrito();*/
        String Mod = JTF_usuario.getText();
        if(Mod.equals("Admin"))
        {
            ventana.setTitle("VENTANA PRINCIPAL - MODO ADMINISTRADOR");
        }
        else
        {
            ventana.setTitle("VENTANA PRINCIPAL - MODO USUARIO");
        }
        ventana.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
}                                                                         

private void JB_Ver_CarritoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    String Usuario = JTF_usuario.getText();
    Carrito Ventana = new Carrito();
    if(Usuario.equals("Admin"))
    {
        Ventana.setTitle("CARRITO MODO - ADMINISTRADOR");
        Ventana.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../Imagenes/DRey_Logo.jpg")).getImage());
        Ventana.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        Ventana.setTitle("CARRITO MODO - USUARIO");
        Ventana.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../Imagenes/DRey_Logo.jpg")).getImage());
        Ventana.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
        modo = 1;
    }
}                                           

private void JB_Añadir_CarritoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               
    String t1;
    t1=JTF_Total_Rentados.getText();
    if(t1.length()==0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "LLENE TODOS LOS DATOS.");//Mensaje de error.
    }
    else
    {
        añadir_carrito();
    }
}             
}
```

Este es el **error**:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Formularios.Ventana_Rentas.confirmarSalida(Ventana_Rentas.java:64)
>       at Formularios.Ventana_Rentas$1.windowClosing(Ventana_Rentas.java:49)
>       at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2054)
>       at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:305)
>       at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2013)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Formularios.Ventana_Rentas.JB_Regresar_RentasActionPerformed(Ventana_Rentas.java:377)
>       at Formularios.Ventana_Rentas.access$000(Ventana_Rentas.java:12)
>       at Formularios.Ventana_Rentas$3.actionPerformed(Ventana_Rentas.java:167)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No podemos depurar por ti, por favor intenta analizar el codigo y mostrar más informacion. Es demasiado lo que pegaste en la pregunta. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: @Carlos Plascencia lograste resolver el problema?